# Connect to TFS using proxy

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops

I'm using the following code to connect to TFS

```
TfsTeamProjectCollection server = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(serverName));
server.EnsureAuthenticated();
```

It works fine. Recently though we've moved from on-premises TFS to VSTS (in the cloud). The above still works, but a local proxy server has been setup to help speed up our connection. I can configure that by following the above code with this:

```
var versionControlServer = server.GetService<VersionControlServer>();
versionControlServer.ConfigureProxy(proxyName);
```

This seems to connect fine the first time. But, if I restart my app, the `EnsureAuthenticated' call fails with exception:

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerUnauthorizedException: TF30063: You are not authorized to access mycorp.visualstudio.com\mycorp.
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpWebRequest.SendRequest()
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpRequestChannel.Request(TfsMessage message, TimeSpan timeout)
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.Channels.TfsHttpClientBase.Invoke(TfsClientOperation operation, Object[] parameters, TimeSpan timeout, Object[]& outputs)
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.LocationWebService.Connect(Int32 connectOptions, Int32 lastChangeId, Int32 features)
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.FrameworkServerDataProvider.Connect(ConnectOptions connectOptions)
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.FrameworkServerDataProvider.EnsureConnected(ConnectOptions optionsNeeded)
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client.FrameworkServerDataProvider.EnsureAuthenticated()
       at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsConnection.EnsureAuthenticated()
```

To get it working again I've found if I quit Visual Studio I can then delete the folder `"C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache"`. When I run my app again, then it will connect ok. But, this workaround won't work in production.

How can I connect using the proxy and connect more than once?

Comment: What's the detail inner error message?

Answer (score 0):

After install [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 2.28.3 package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/2.28.3) to my project (console application), then it is working fine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.I did see a different exception message a couple of times that mentioned failure to load that dll. I think the message said it was looking for version 2.16 of the dll. I'm not 100% certain on the version number. The version you've advised me to download is 3.something. Installing it doesn't seem to have made any difference. I wonder if it's the wrong version. I can't seem to reproduce getting the exception message that includes the dlls version number. I now only get the exception message as posted in the question.

Comment: @ScottLangham Is Inner error message the same as you said that "You are not authorized to access". The inner message of my is cannot load Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 2.16. Fixed by installing 2.28.3. On the other hand, I am using extended client package(https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/)